# How to Source all powershell scripts from a directory

Tags: powershell

Can not dot source all PowerShell scripts from directory
tried:

```
. .\*.ps1
```

Returns this:

```
>  : The term '.\*.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
> name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
> try again. At line:1 char:3
> + . .\*.ps1
> +   ~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\*.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: I wish `. .\*.ps1` worked

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `Get-ChildItem` to grab all `*.ps1` files, then loop through them with `ForEach-Object` and dot-source them individually

```
$Path = "C:\Scripts\Directory"
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter *.ps1 |ForEach-Object {
    . $_.FullName
}
```

---

If you put the above in a script, and the script itself is located in `$Path`, make sure to exclude the file itself so as to avoid it recursively dot-sourcing itself over and over again:

```
$Path = "C:\Scripts\Directory"
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter *.ps1 |Where-Object { $_.FullName -ne $PSCommandPath } |ForEach-Object {
    . $_.FullName
}
```

---

Edit: jcolebrand - 2018-06-25

Used the above to define a folder called Functions under my executing script. Works just fine in PS5:

```
## Folder\myIncluder.ps1
## Folder\Functions\Some-Function.ps1          -included
## Folder\Functions\Some-Other-Function.ps1    -included
## Folder\Functions\Some-Other-Function.readme -not included
(Get-ChildItem -Path (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot Functions) -Filter *.ps1 -Recurse) | % {
    . $_.FullName
}
```

Figure this makes it easy for the next lazy person to just adopt the same structure :p

Comment: If I add this command to a file, source it and execute, it hangs. By any chance, do you know how can I put this command in file such that it works?

Comment: That's because it recursively starts dot-sourcing itself, that can be fixed though, let me update the answer

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.ps1' | Foreach { . $_.FullName }
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can loop through all your PowerShell files, and source them:

```
foreach ($ps1 in (ls *.ps1)) {
    . $ps1.FullName
}
```